# lightning node data visibility on explorers

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I'm trying to set my first c-lightning node with docker-compose using image from https://hub.docker.com/r/elementsproject/lightningd. currently, my node can connect and open channel with other nodes (and I can open a channel to the node just fine), but it's still not updated (ie has no information) on most explorers.

the following is result of `getinfo` and `listconfigs`

```
getinfo
{
   "id": "03db40337c2de299a8fa454fdf89d311615d50a27129d43286696d9e497b2b027a",
   "alias": "TestName",
   "color": "fff000",
   "num_peers": 3,
   "num_pending_channels": 0,
   "num_active_channels": 3,
   "num_inactive_channels": 0,
   "address": [
      {
         "type": "ipv4",
         "address": "68.183.195.14",
         "port": 9735
      }
   ],
   "binding": [
      {
         "type": "ipv4",
         "address": "172.18.0.3",
         "port": 9735
      }
   ],
   "version": "v0.7.1-906-gf657146",
   "blockheight": 601917,
   "network": "bitcoin",
   "msatoshi_fees_collected": 0,
   "fees_collected_msat": "0msat"
}

listconfigs    
{
   "# version": "v0.7.1-906-gf657146",
   "lightning-dir": "/root/.lightning",
   "wallet": "sqlite3:///root/.lightning/lightningd.sqlite3",
   "plugin": "/usr/local/bin/../libexec/c-lightning/plugins/pay",
   "plugin": "/usr/local/bin/../libexec/c-lightning/plugins/autoclean",
   "plugin": "/usr/local/bin/../libexec/c-lightning/plugins/fundchannel",
   "network": "bitcoin",
   "allow-deprecated-apis": true,
   "always-use-proxy": false,
   "daemon": "false",
   "rpc-file": "lightning-rpc",
   "rgb": "fff000",
   "alias": "HubTest",
   "bitcoin-rpcuser": [redacted],
   "bitcoin-rpcpassword": [redacted],
   "bitcoin-rpcconnect": "bitcoind",
   "bitcoin-retry-timeout": 60,
   "pid-file": "lightningd-bitcoin.pid",
   "ignore-fee-limits": false,
   "watchtime-blocks": 144,
   "max-locktime-blocks": 2016,
   "funding-confirms": 3,
   "commit-fee-min": 200,
   "commit-fee-max": 2000,
   "commit-fee": 500,
   "cltv-delta": 14,
   "cltv-final": 10,
   "commit-time": 10,
   "fee-base": 0,
   "rescan": 15,
   "fee-per-satoshi": 1,
   "max-concurrent-htlcs": 30,
   "min-capacity-sat": 10000,
   "bind-addr": "172.18.0.3:9735",
   "announce-addr": "68.183.195.14:9735",
   "offline": "false",
   "autolisten": true,
   "disable-dns": "false",
   "enable-autotor-v2-mode": "false",
   "encrypted-hsm": false,
   "log-level": "DEBUG",
   "log-prefix": "lightningd(7):"
}
```

is there something wrong with this configuration? or is it another issue?

I understand that explorers update their node list irregularly, and as far as the node can open channels (and can be connected), everything is fine. but this thing has bugging me for weeks.

Comment: Your node is [visible on explorers](https://1ml.com/node/03db40337c2de299a8fa454fdf89d311615d50a27129d43286696d9e497b2b027a). I think what you mean to ask is why the explorers do not show additional data (like color, IP, alias) related to your node ID.

Comment: sorry, I must be confused with the definition. you are right, I'm wondering about alias color, and IP address. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated the docker image and put `bind-addr` to `0.0.0.0:9375` somehow fixed the problem for some unknown reason.